# Why does my like button return a Json object { liked: true } but doesn't work with my ajax call in Django when a user clicks the like button

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-models, django-views

I have been trying to create a like button with calling an ajax function in Django, But somehow whenever i click on the like button it redirect me to different page with a json object that return  {liked : true }. why am getting this issue! it's been a challenge for me to figure it out and does it having any thing to do with my javascripts or with my function in views.py how better can i do this to stop the effect! and make the page not to reload when users like! Here's my like function!

```
def like(request, pk, c_slug=None):
    user = request.user
    if request.POST.get("operation") == "like_submit" and is_ajax(request=request):
               liked=get_object_or_404(Like,pk=pk)
    product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk, slug=c_slug)
    liked= False
    like = Like.objects.filter(user_like=user, product=product)
    if like:
        like.delete()
    else:
        liked = True
        Like.objects.create(user_like=user, product=product)
        resp = {
        'liked':liked,
         }
        response = json.dumps(resp)
        return HttpResponse(response,content_type = "application/json")
```

model.py

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user_like = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='user_likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='user_likes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    like_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

This is my scriepts for ajax call

```
<script>
    $(".like").click(function (e) {
    var id = this.id;
    var href = $('.like').find('a').attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: href,
        data: 
        {'liked': $(this).attr('name'),
        'operation':'like_submit',
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function(response){
          if(response.liked){
            $('#likebtn' + id).html("Unlike");
            $('#likebtn' + id).css("color", "gray")
          }
          else{
            $('#likebtn' + id).html("Like");
            $('#likebtn' + id).css("color", "blue")
          }
        }
      })
});
</script>
```

my HTML

```
{% if product in liked %}
<a href='{% url "shop:like" product.id product.slug %}' id="likebtn{{ product.id }}"  class="flexitems-center space-x-2">
<div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black lg:bg-gray-10">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="blue" width="22"height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
     <path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
     </svg>
         </div>
              <div >Unlike</div></a>
    {% else %}
  <a href='{% url "shop:like" product.id product.slug %}' id="likebtn{{ product.id }}"  class="flex items-center space-x-2">
    <div class="p-2 rounded-full text-black lg:bg-gray-10">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" width="22" height="22" class="dark:text-gray-100">
<path d="M2 10.5a1.5 1.5 0 113 0v6a1.5 1.5 0 01-3 0v-6zM6 10.333v5.43a2 2 0 001.106 1.79l.05.025A4 4 0 008.943 18h5.416a2 2 0 001.962-1.608l1.2-6A2 2 0 0015.56 8H12V4a2 2 0 00-2-2 1 1 0 00-1 1v.667a4 4 0 01-.8 2.4L6.8 7.933a4 4 0 00-.8 2.4z" />
  </svg>
   </div>
      <div >Like</div>
        </a>
   {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you actually have a like button, instead you have links to your like url - so obviously clicking those links is going to take you to those urls. It also doesn't look like any of your elements have the `like` class, so your JQuery AJAX code doesn't get triggered by anything.

I would suggest using an actual `<button>` HTML element - if you attached a `like` class to it then it should work as intended.

Comment: I tried your solution but am still getting the same effect after adding the like class, I get redirected to the json object { liked : true } and also added the button!

Comment: Did you remove the <a> tags? That is what will take you to a new page

Comment: Yes i jus did but it doesn't change to False, it stays on True even though now it doesn't redirect me again after i had taking the <a > tags out!